# What is the best way to mock q-io/http requests?

Tags: node.js, q, nock

I'm trying to write unit tests for my `HTTP service`.  My service interacts with another remote `HTTP service`, and I'm using using `q-io/http` for that interaction.

I would like to use something like the nock package to mock my calls to the remote service, but q-io/http does not seem to be compatible with nock (***I'm assuming that this means that the request module is not actually used under the covers of `q-io/http` as I'd hoped***).

Are there any other approaches to mocking `q-io/http` requests?  There does not seem to be an http mocking capability included in Q like there is for files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that q-io/http does indeed use the standard request module under the covers, and subsequently, it is possible to use nock with the q-io/http module.

For me, the problem was that nock was not matching my requests, and the exception was getting swallowed up in a catch.  Using the nock log(console.log) mechanism made the matching problems obvious:

```
nock(documentUrl)
  .delete('/state')
  .reply(204, {})
  .log(console.log);
```